# Не могу получить доступ к глобальной переменной и записать ее [Android]

Tags: java, android, переменные, global-variables

Всем привет!
Необходимо получить доступ к глобальной переменной из public void, записать в нее данные и уже обновленную с новыми данными получить за пределами public void. Но не выходит, данные не записываются в переменную, либо не передаются за пределы Public void

Думаю по коду будет понятно)

```
public class SDFixFragment extends Fragment {
    // Объявляется глобальная переменная
    public int s;
...

@Override
 public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (RootTools.isBusyboxAvailable()) {
                    if (RootTools.isRootAvailable()) {
                        if (RootTools.isAccessGiven()) {
                            Command command1 = new Command(0, "my_command") {
                                @Override
                                public void commandOutput(int id, String line) {
                                    super.commandOutput(id, line);
                                    if (line.contains("EXCUTED")) {
                                        ...
                                        // Происходит запись единицы
                                        s=1;

                                    } else {

                                      ...
         }
        ...
  // Проверка записанного значения, находится в onViewCreated()
  if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) && (s==1)) 
            {
             .....
            }
  }
```

Comment: а точно ничем не перекрыли это переменную?

Comment: @pavel по моим расчетам так нет

Comment: @NowenUI у вас проверка записанного значения гласит, что если версия сдк выше 23 И s == 1, то выполняется условие. Напомню, логическое И - это когда все должно быть тру, чтобы условие было выполнено. Тут как минимум ,я считаю врядли у вас 23 + версия.  Подскажите на каком эмуляторе \ версии тестировали?

Comment: @Asgard Тут видите какая ситуация, мне надо чтобы это условие выполнялось только если девайс имеет версию Android 6.0 и если переменная равна 1. Да, иначе кнопка просто блокируется. Тестирую на реальном девайсе на Android 6.0

Comment: Выглядит как race condition. Переменная s обновляется асинхронно, в потоке, и кто знает, когда это произойдет.

Comment: То что вы запостили в поток задачу ещё не означает что она выполнится до проверки записанного значения. Она выполнится когда до нее дойдет очередь и это будет точно после вашей проверки.

Comment: Решил проблему избавлением от переменной и её проверки, переделал код по логике, все работает